# How to connect interfaces' shields?

Tags: pcb-design, usb, connector, shielding, rj45

I am designing a new PCB board these days, and I am confused about how to connect interfaces' shields. The interfaces on the board include USB, RJ45 and D-SUB, should them be connected directly to signal GND? I've seen a lot of solutions these days and I don't still konw which one is the easiest and at least effective.

I am only responsible for drawing the schematic diagram. The PCB routing is handed over to other engineers and is almost finished. Currently, there is no dedicated GND layer for shields on the board, I just hope to find a good solution that does not require a lot of changes. Thanks.

PS. The board containes both USB host and USB slave interfaces. RJ45 is used for Gigabit Ethernet port. There are currently 6 D-SUB interfaces, two of which are used to transmit analog signals (generally concerned with frequencies of several hundred hertz), and the rest are used to transmit low-rate digital signals (Mhz).

Comment: It depends on what those interfaces are, and is it a USB host or USB device. RJ45 and D-SUB connectors can carry anything. Would you fill in the required information what interfaces those connectors have?

Comment: I assume you're talking about cable shields?

Comment: And do you have a grounding diagram for your system?  How are signal returns (signal ground) connected to chassis?

Comment: This board is a test board and may not be placed in the chassis. The ground can only be connected to the ground of the DC power input.

Comment: Is the gigabit ethernet handled with separate transformer or integrated magjack?

Comment: It's an integrted magjack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in a position to fully evaluate this then make connections to ground from the shields but via an 0603 footprint that can be optionally fitted with a zero ohm link or capacitor when the time is appropriate for making that decision.

Some ground connections may indeed require capacitors fitted (rather than a galvanic connection) and sometimes (ethernet particularly) I've see 1 kV rated capacitors fitted such as 2.2 nF. So, find a suitable footprint for a 2.2 nF capacitor rated at 1 kV and, maybe use that as the "to be fitted" component. But, for now leave them unfitted and test the board to see what is appropriate.

Leave your options open if it isn't too inconvenient!

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It's helpful.

Comment: @JJbow if there is nothing left to answer on this question please [take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand people's motivation for making an answer and consider formally accepting the answer. If you still have residual concerns that need to be addressed regarding your question please leave a comment below this one.